# error: Attribute "***" has already been defined when using two library projects in Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, xml-attribute

I'm using **android-support-v7-appcompat** as a library in my Android project. Now I want to include **actionbarsherlock** as another library project. When I add the second library, it gives so many errors like below

```
android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml:476: error: Attribute "attributeName" has already been defined
```

By changing one attribute value and it's related code snippet is a one solution that I've tried. But when there are nearly 80 lines like above, it will get a messy. Is there any other way I can solve this issue?

Comment: This is not the answer. But in my case I have used above both libraries to get the ActionBar features. So I have removed **android-support-v7-appcompat** and continued.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to solve this problem is by updating Android Support Libraries in all relevant projects and library projects. In my case I've used Android support library and also one of the library project to implement my application. When I update both libraries, the problem solved. The way of updating Android support library is;

- Right click on the project
- Select ***Android Tools*** from the pop up window
- Select ***Add Support Library***

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm trying the exact same thing as AnujAroshA - using android-support-v7-appcompat as a library as well as ActionBarSherlock. I get the same error. I've updated the support libraries like you've suggested (and this I knew), and then cleaned all three projects. No luck.

Comment: How can I update the library I am importing? It is just a 'compile "libraryhere"' statement.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the appcompact support library project from *Properties* = > *Android*

Answer (score 3):

Gradle Resource Merger merges all resource folders from all dependencies and place into single folder. In case there are duplicates build process will fail.

Fortunately, if you look below under Output: label, you will find the right path to the problem.

Here is an example

[image]

in your case it is 
`android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml:476: error: Attribute "attributeName" has already been defined`

You can also build your project from command line and get the right path.
attributeName
Inside `values\attrs.xml` file on line 476 you would find a  with property named "attributeName". Most probably it is your own styleable that you have to change to get rid of the duplicate.

So now, when you know the reason, you can locate that property in your project module and replace it with different name.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing appcompact from project, and changing in styles to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the build tools version and resynced, it worked fine.