# while using support library i am getting an error that Attribute " " has already been defined in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using android version 4.2.2(API 17) and i am getting a lot of errors in the console.The errors are in the format of [[[Attribute " " has already been defined in android]]]
inside the quotes a lot of values present.For example title,height,isLightTheme,windowActionBar color,spinBars,drawableSize,gapBetweenBars,topBottomBarArrowSize etc.....
The console is shown below.....

```
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:28: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:29: error: Attribute "height" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:31: error: Attribute "isLightTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:43: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:48: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:52: error: Attribute "windowActionModeOverlay" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:57: error: Attribute "windowFixedWidthMajor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:61: error: Attribute "windowFixedHeightMinor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:66: error: Attribute "windowFixedWidthMinor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:70: error: Attribute "windowFixedHeightMajor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:79: error: Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:80: error: Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:81: error: Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:82: error: Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:83: error: Attribute "actionOverflowMenuStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:86: error: Attribute "actionBarPopupTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:88: error: Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:93: error: Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:97: error: Attribute "actionBarTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:105: error: Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:108: error: Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:112: error: Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:114: error: Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:117: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:120: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:127: error: Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:128: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:130: error: Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:132: error: Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:134: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:136: error: Attribute "actionModeCutDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:138: error: Attribute "actionModeCopyDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:140: error: Attribute "actionModePasteDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:142: error: Attribute "actionModeSelectAllDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:144: error: Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:146: error: Attribute "actionModeFindDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:148: error: Attribute "actionModeWebSearchDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:151: error: Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:159: error: Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:161: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:170: error: Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:172: error: Attribute "dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:175: error: Attribute "spinnerStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:177: error: Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:179: error: Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:182: error: Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:186: error: Attribute "buttonBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:189: error: Attribute "buttonBarButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:193: error: Attribute "selectableItemBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:195: error: Attribute "selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:197: error: Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:199: error: Attribute "dividerHorizontal" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:201: error: Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:204: error: Attribute "toolbarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:206: error: Attribute "toolbarNavigationButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:209: error: Attribute "popupMenuStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:211: error: Attribute "popupWindowStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:214: error: Attribute "editTextColor" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:216: error: Attribute "editTextBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:219: error: Attribute "switchStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:226: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:228: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:230: error: Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:232: error: Attribute "searchViewStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:240: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:242: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:244: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightLarge" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:247: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:249: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:252: error: Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:253: error: Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:256: error: Attribute "textAppearanceListItem" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:258: error: Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:267: error: Attribute "panelBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:269: error: Attribute "panelMenuListWidth" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:271: error: Attribute "panelMenuListTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:273: error: Attribute "listChoiceBackgroundIndicator" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:282: error: Attribute "colorPrimary" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:286: error: Attribute "colorPrimaryDark" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:290: error: Attribute "colorAccent" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:293: error: Attribute "colorControlNormal" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:296: error: Attribute "colorControlActivated" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:299: error: Attribute "colorControlHighlight" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:302: error: Attribute "colorButtonNormal" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:305: error: Attribute "colorSwitchThumbNormal" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:321: error: Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:330: error: Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:342: error: Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:344: error: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:346: error: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:348: error: Attribute "icon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:350: error: Attribute "logo" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:352: error: Attribute "divider" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:354: error: Attribute "background" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:356: error: Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:358: error: Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:360: error: Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:364: error: Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:366: error: Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:368: error: Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:370: error: Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:375: error: Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:377: error: Attribute "hideOnContentScroll" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:380: error: Attribute "contentInsetStart" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:383: error: Attribute "contentInsetEnd" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:386: error: Attribute "contentInsetLeft" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:389: error: Attribute "contentInsetRight" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:391: error: Attribute "elevation" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:394: error: Attribute "popupTheme" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:418: error: Attribute "closeItemLayout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:423: error: Attribute "paddingStart" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:425: error: Attribute "paddingEnd" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:452: error: Attribute "preserveIconSpacing" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:534: error: Attribute "showAsAction" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:559: error: Attribute "actionLayout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:564: error: Attribute "actionViewClass" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:570: error: Attribute "actionProviderClass" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:576: error: Attribute "prompt" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:578: error: Attribute "spinnerMode" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:600: error: Attribute "popupPromptView" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:605: error: Attribute "disableChildrenWhenDisabled" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:611: error: Attribute "layout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:614: error: Attribute "iconifiedByDefault" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:618: error: Attribute "queryHint" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:624: error: Attribute "closeIcon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:626: error: Attribute "goIcon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:628: error: Attribute "searchIcon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:630: error: Attribute "voiceIcon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:632: error: Attribute "commitIcon" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:634: error: Attribute "suggestionRowLayout" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:636: error: Attribute "queryBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:638: error: Attribute "submitBackground" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:645: error: Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:652: error: Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:657: error: Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:683: error: Attribute "measureWithLargestChild" has already been defined
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] 
[2014-12-18 10:22:16 - sample] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:687: error: Attribute "showDividers" has already been defined
```

any help will be appreciated.advance thanks.......

Comment: I suspect your project is reference multiple support libraries. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995970/error-attribute-has-already-been-defined-when-using-two-library-projects

Comment: but its not working for me..I updated Android Support Libraries in all relevant projects and library projects.But showing the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it solved the same problem to me when i was adding the ShowCaseView library to my project:

The problem was that some library I used was importing the ***android-support-v7-appcompact*** and I was importing the library ***JWAction-Bar-Shrelock***.
It semms that the cannot be imported togheter.

> Solution:
>
> - Check in Properties / Android / Librarys wich librarys are you importing, and remove one of the two.
> - Check what *jars* you added on the **libs** folder for the >comfliction imports.

Hope this helps.