# Error while making module Android Studio: "showDividers" has already been defined

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, makefile, android-gradle-plugin

---

I'm new with AndroidStudio. And I'm trying to import and old Eclipse Library Android Project ( already exported to use gradle ). 
But, when I try to do 'Make Module', a lot of errors about attributes thathas already been defined. Here is the AndroidStudio's screenshot:
[image: androidstudio screnshot]

Have you ever seen this error? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem. I have projects wich depends each other. One of this projects was using another project as dependency, and both wa setted to use the appcompat-v7. That was causing the error of "attribute already defined".

Here, the link that helped me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798212/988521